# Switch between two versions of software renaming folders with a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I need to switch between two version of the same software all the time. Lets say "St5" and "St6". The both versions are using the same settings so I need to launch them from the same folder (C:/St). For this reason I need to rename the folder version I need to work from "St5" or "St6" to "St" .I have both versions in separate folders, and I'm renaming one that I need to be in (C:/St) and after that I'm launching that version from the "St" folder. For this reason I need to create two different .bat files (St5.bat and St6.bat) who will check what version of the software in in the "St" folder and if needed to rename the folders and launch the software or if not to just launch the software.

Because I need to identify the version that I have into each folder I created a .txt file in each folder containing the version of the software that is contained in that folder, in this case "_St_5.txt" and "_St_6.txt".

I created one .bat file to make the things more automatic but unfortunately I can't make this to work. Bellow is my attempt to achieve my goal, but I don't understand what is wrong. Please help.

=======================

```
IF EXIST C:\St\\_St_5.txt (
start /d "C:\St" St.exe
)

ELSE (

for /D %%f in "C:\St\" do rename "St" "St6"
rename "C:\St5" "C:\St"

start /d "C:\St" St.exe

)

exit
```

Comment: `else` cannot be used as standalone command. Try to put it on line with the brackets like `) else (`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I made the change you requested but when I'm running the St5.bat I'm receiving the following message:
===================
>C:\St5.bat
"C:\St" was unexpected at this time.

>for /D %f in "C:\St" do rename "St" "St6"

Comment: check again the `for /d` syntax . Like the brackets which are mandatory- http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for this task the following commented batch file:

```
@echo off
rem First always check if application ST is currently not running.

:CheckRunning
cls
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq St.exe" 2>nul | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "St.exe" >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto CheckVersion
echo.
echo ST is currently running. Please exit all instances of ST.
echo.
pause
goto CheckRunning

:CheckVersion
if "%~1" == "5" (
    if exist C:\St5\* goto SwitchToST5
    goto StartST
)
if "%~1" == "6" (
    if exist C:\St6\* goto SwitchToST6
    goto StartST
)
goto ToggleVersion

rem If there is the directory C:\St5, the directory C:\St contains
rem version 6 of application ST. Therefore a switch from version 6 to
rem version 5 must be done now. Otherwise C:\St contains version 5 of
rem application ST and therefore a switch from version 5 to version 6
rem must be done now.

rem NOTE: There is no check made if directory C:\St exists at all and
rem       if the directory renames are both successful. A directory
rem       rename could fail if any running process uses one of the two
rem       directories or a subdirectory of them as current directory or
rem       there is a file from the directories opened by an application.

:ToggleVersion
if exist C:\St5\* goto SwitchToST5
if exist C:\St6\* goto SwitchToST6

echo.
echo ERROR: There is whether C:\St5 nor C:\St6
echo        Please add the missing directory.
echo.
pause
exit /B

rem Switch from active version 5 to version 6.
:SwitchToST6
ren C:\St St5
ren C:\St6 St
goto StartST

rem Switch from active version 6 to version 5.
:SwitchToST5
ren C:\St St6
ren C:\St5 St

:StartST
start "" /D "C:\St" St.exe
```

A single batch file is enough to toggle between two versions of an application. Either `C:\St` contains currently version 6 which means there is additionally just `C:\St5` or `C:\St` contains currently version 5 and so there is additionally just `C:\St6`. The version toggle is done depending on which directory exists additionally to `C:\St` by running two directory rename operations.

But the batch file first checks on any running instance of the application before the directory renames are done as it would not be good to try to rename the directories while the application is currently running.

The batch file can be also used to start a specific version.

If the batch file is started with `5` as parameter, it always starts version 5 with making the appropriate directory renames if that is necessary because version 6 is currently the active version.

If the batch file is started with `6` as parameter, it always starts version 6 with making the appropriate directory renames if that is necessary because version 5 is currently the active version.

The batch file simply toggles the active version if started with any other parameter or with no parameter.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cls /?`
- `call /?` ... for an explanation of `%~1` (first parameter without double quotes).
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `find /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `ren /?`
- `start /?`
- `tasklist /?`

This batch file can't be stored in `C:\St` or `C:\St5` or `C:\St6`.

But it should be also not stored on Windows Desktop. The Windows Desktop is designed for containing only shortcuts, i.e. *.lnk files. The Windows Desktop is implemented by Microsoft as a folder and can therefore contain also other files and folders. But in general it is no good idea to have other files or even folders on Windows Desktop for various reasons which I don't want to list here.

The batch file could be stored in directory `%ProgramFiles%`. But saving the batch file in this directory requires administrator privileges. However, this directory is nevertheless a good location for a batch file used by any user of the computer and being executed usually only via shortcuts.

A good place for a batch file used only by a single user is the application data directory. Clicking with primary (left) mouse button on address bar of Windows Explorer, entering `%APPDATA%` and hitting key <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> opens this user account related folder where the current user has also write access. Windows Explorer automatically expands this reference to environment variable **APPDATA** and displays the name of this folder with full path.

Creating a shortcut to a file/folder on Windows Desktop is quite simple. There are several methods.

One method is clicking with secondary (right) mouse button on a free area on Windows Desktop and left clicking with primary (left) mouse button on menu item **Shortcut** in submenu **New** of the context menu. After browsing to file/folder (batch file in this case) and entering the name for the shortcut, the shortcut (*.lnk file) is created with default settings.

Another method is clicking with right mouse button on the file/folder itself (the batch file in this case) and clicking with left mouse button on **Desktop (create shortcut)** in submenu **Send To** or menu item **Create shortcut** in context menu to create a shortcut to the file/folder directly on Windows Desktop or in current folder which next must be cut from current folder and pasted on Windows Desktop. The available shortcut creating menu item depends on version of Windows, see for example the page [Windows Help - Create or delete a shortcut](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-delete-shortcut).

The file name of the *.lnk is the shortcut name. Therefore the shortcut can be renamed like any other file with right clicking on the shortcut and left clicking on **Rename** in context menu. A short meaningful name is always helpful for a shortcut.

For the shortcut to the batch file starting application ST in version 5 it is necessary to right click on the shortcut file and left click on last context menu item **Properties**. A window opens with several options to configure.

The first one is the target command line where the batch file name is displayed with full path enclosed in double quotes if the string contains 1 or more spaces. On this string there must be appended on right side a space character and `5` to run the batch file with `5` as parameter on later clicking on the shortcut.

The batch file outputs nothing on no error. It just starts the application in version 5. Therefore it makes sense to run the batch file with **Minimized** window set for **Run**. The application ST started from within the batch file is started with normal window. Just the batch file is processed with a minimized console window.

The icon of a shortcut to a batch file is by default a console window symbol. It is definitely better for this shortcut to click on button **Change Icon**, browse to `C:\St\St.exe` and select the first icon inside the executable. A GUI application has usually 1 or more icons. Otherwise there are usually 1 or even more *.ico files in the folder of the application to use for shortcuts.

The first shortcut for starting version 5 of `St.exe` via batch file is ready after closing the shortcut properties window with a click on button **OK**.

For the second shortcut starting version 6 of `St.exe` via batch file copy with Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V the already created shortcut, rename this copy, open the shortcut properties, replace `5` by `6` on target command line, and close the window with button **OK**.

See also the article [How to automatically start a program minimized in Windows?](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-automatically-start-a-program-minimized-in-windows/) with screenshots of a shortcut properties window. It depends on version of Windows how the shortcut properties window looks like and also on type of shortcut, but the main options as described above are available in all shortcut properties.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I will need two .bat files to make a clear distinction which version I want to run. The way described above don't take into account this. It is just more easier for me co create two .bat files on my desktop and run the one that corresponds to the version of the software I want to run. "St6.bat" if I want to run version 6 of the software or "St5.bat" if I want to run the version 5 of the software.

Comment: I enhanced the batch file to make it possible switching to version 5 or 6 depending on a parameter. So you can use this single batch file to toggle current version, to start version 5 or to start version 6. Create two shortcuts to the batch file, first one with `5` as parameter on the command line in the shortcut properties and second one with `6` as parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I still think that I will need two separate bat files because I don't know how to add the requested parameter in the command line. Also, I think will be much easier to check the version of the software from every folder by identifying the filename that exists in every folder. I have one file called _St5.txt inside of the folder ST5 and another file called _St6.txt inside of the folder St6.

Comment: Checking name of a folder or name of a file does not make a difference. In both cases `if exist` is used to check if file/folder exists. It looks like you don't know even the basics on using of Windows like how to create and modify a shortcut or even know what a shortcut is. There are thousands of pages, lots of free ebooks, and free Windows tours (by Microsoft and others) to learn the basics on using Windows. I added to my answer a short general description on how to create shortcuts and change their properties. I could not write a step by step description as not knowing your Windows version.